# What is the best practice for sum array with same key

Tags: php, arrays, isset, arrayobject

For example:

```
$output = array();
foreach($data as $row) {
    if(!isset($output[$row->foo][$row->bar])) {
        $output[$row->foo][$row->bar] = 0;
    }        
    $output[$row->foo][$row->bar] += $row->value;
}
```

It is possible to use some object to skip the part with `if(!isset(...))`?

I tryed overload `ArrayObject` and `offsetGet` method, but there was a problem with reference, [see the php forum](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.offsetget.php#79496).

Answer (score 0):

You can actually just leave the entire `if` block out. A relatively simple example:

```
<?
$x[15][12] += 5;
var_dump($x);
?>
```

will dump

```
array(1) {
  [15]=>
  array(1) {
    [12]=>
    int(5)
  }
}
```

---

Depending on your php.ini settings, you may get a warning about a missing index, but you can [suppress the warning with an `@`](http://php.net/@) at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a clean way, without ignoring warnings